# why still dns lookup when using proxy?

Tags: proxy, dns, wireshark

I've configured my browser(firefox) to use proxy ,but I find that it's still looking up the dns when I visit http://domain.name, why is that still necessary?

Comment: HTTP or SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 2):

Even when connecting via a proxy your browser needs to get the IP address for the web site domain. Generally it will directly query the DNS servers. If you are using a Socks 5 proxy, you can have the DNS queries go through your proxy. There is a check box for that in the Proxies option panel in Firefox.

Comment: Why does the browser need to know the IP address for the web site domain when it's using proxy?I don't think it's necessary at all...

Comment: As explained: DNS queries are not performed by the proxy. If you want DNS queries to be performed by the proxy, then you have to use a proxy protocol that tells the proxy to do that, eg. SOCKS 5.

Comment: More generally what people _think_ is necessary, in the context of browser internals, is very rarely correct.

Comment: @Rushyo: HTTP proxy servers _always_ perform DNS queries (confirmed by watching raw traffic), as do SOCKS 4a and optionally SOCKS 5 proxies. It's only SOCKS 4 that requires the browser to do it.

Comment: Ok let me put it another way: It's based on the implementation - shorthand for what I wrote.